# Intent.getStringExtra("key") returning null

Tags: java, string, android-intent, android-activity, null

I've looked at other people's issues on this same subject and haven't been able to solve the issue. The code on my main activity looks like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultsActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
i.putExtra("dob", dobStr);
i.putExtra("gender", gender);
```

`dobStr` and `gender` are both strings (I have tested this by replacing `dobStr` with an actual string with quotes). My second activity is named `ResultsActivity`.

My second activity has this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String dob = i.getStringExtra("dob");
String gender = i.getStringExtra("gender");
```

but `dob` and `gender` are both null.

Can someone help me figure out the issue?

Comment: Are dob and gender in ResultsActivity still both null when you, as you said in the question, replaced dobStr and gender in your first activity with hardcoded strings?

Comment: May be you should invoke `startActivity` after the two `putExtra` calls?

Comment: @Nondeterministicnarwhal Yes

Comment: @NishantShreshth That worked. I'm not sure how I didn't think of that before. I would mark this as correct but I'm not sure I can on a comment. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I'll write the same as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invoke `startActivity` after the two `putExtra` calls.